# "Baviera" ou "Bavária"?

Tags: uso-de-palavras

Na Alemanha, há um estado cujo nome alemão é Bayern, ou Baiern. No português, esse estado tem, aparentemente, dois nomes: Bavária e Baviera.

Então, pergunto: deve-se usar *Bavária* ou *Baviera*, em português?

Comment: Mas "Baviera" nao vem do frances "Baviére"? (E nós sabemos como o Portuges/Brasileiro adora tudo o que é "Francais"). O anglo-saxonico "Bavária" me parece mais próximo... mais lógico...

Comment: @RicardoLeitner Esse anglo-saxonico é um barbaridade.

Answer (score 4):

"Baviera" é o correto em português para *Bayern*.

Como a [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baviera) coloca:

> É comum o uso do latinismo "Bavária", também influenciado pela forma inglesa do topônimo. Todavia, segundo o Dicionário Onomástico Etimológico da Língua Portuguesa, o registro vernáculo é apenas "Baviera".

Também a Infopédia registra "[Baviera](https://www.infopedia.pt/$baviera)", mas não Bavária*.